# Check if list is in table

Tags: mysql, sql

Hey Stackoverflow community!

I currently use a temporary table to store the list of arrays are compare which ones don't exist within the table and insert those but I'm hoping there is a quicker more optimized way.

My goal is to get this down to one query

1.) I have an array of c_no INTs (1,2,3,4,5) I would like to add to a group_join table.

2.) In the groups_join I need to preform the following query to get all c_no values currently in the table.

```
 select c_no from groups_join where g_no = (INT)
```

to see what INT's are in the groups

3.) I need someway to check if any of the c_no INTs I will be inserting are already in the groups_join table with same the g_no so I don't have duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot comment due to rep, but in response to your comment on Didier's answer, instead of `INSERT` you can use `INSERT IGNORE` after you've created your `unique index`. When you use `INSERT IGNORE` MySQL will not insert the value, but will also suppress the error thrown due to attempting to insert a duplicate `unique index`. This will allow you to add your unique index without have to write code to handle the error.

```
INSERT [LOW_PRIORITY | DELAYED | HIGH_PRIORITY] [IGNORE]
    [INTO] tbl_name [(col_name,...)]
    {VALUES | VALUE} ({expr | DEFAULT},...),(...),...
    [ ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
      col_name=expr
        [, col_name=expr] ...
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html

Answer (score 3):

I guess you are looking for the `IN` Keyword.

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE field IN (myList)
```

If you want the g_no field to have unique values, why do you don't add the `unique` index ? [MySQL Document - Create Index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html)

Comment: Hey @Didier,  I'm trying to determine a list of c_no INTs that is not in the table though. That way I can insert the records without having a duplicate. A unique index would work but we'd have to incorporate error handling in the code.

Answer (score 1):

To insert array values that doesn't already exist in your `groups_join` table, you would need to use `NOT EXISTS` something like this:

```
INSERT INTO groups_join(c_no)
SELECT c_no
FROM yourTempTable yt
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM groups_join gj
        WHERE yt.c_no = gj.c_no
        );
```